# Cannot delete contents in editText with backSpace?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

There is an editText with textWatcher applied. As you see in the below Gif, I cannot delete the numbers from end of the EditText, but first. When locale is english everything works fine, but not in arabic language.

[image]

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/destination"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="19"
        android:digits="0123456789-"
        android:hint="@string/to"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't arabic read from right to left? So left is actually the end.

Ok, try adding `android:inputType="number"`

Comment: If it was an arabic sentence, you were right, but numbers are the same as english language. I think I have to set a layout direction to this field.

Comment: @Patzu I didn't know numbers are the same. I edited my answer, I think you need to set the inputType on the EditText

Comment: look at the third line of xml that I added, it's already there.